# Conda Environment customization: Place local site-packages ahead of derived

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment, miniconda

I have a global miniconda installation which users can clone into their own areas and add packages, etc. However, when you do:

```
conda create -p </path/to/new/env> --clone </path/to/global/miniconda>
```

Then

```
source activate </path/to/new/env>
```

You find that

```
python -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'
```

places the `path/to/new/env/lib/pythonX/site-packages` at the end. This means the users installed packages will not be preferred over the global. Also, it appears then entire global site-packages are copied into the users new environment.

Is there a way to create a conda environment, which does not duplicate all the global packages, but prioritizes the user's custom environment site-packages ahead of the global site-packages? That saves disk space, but still allows the user to install updated packages, etc.

Comment: The `clone` option implies, to me, that the entire environment should be cloned - packages and everything. Is the global `site-packages` still on `sys.path`?

Comment: I would think the same, though the global site-packages is the first listed in `sys.path`.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior... perhaps because I'm using the `-n` option instead of `-p`. What if you use `-n`?

Comment: The problem with `-n` is that it then tries to create the environment in the global area `/path/to/global/env`.

Comment: OK, I ran `conda create -p ~/miniconda3/envs/clone-test --clone ~/miniconda3/envs/cantera-dev` and `conda activate ~/miniconda3/envs/clone-test` and the `sys.path` is: `['', '~/miniconda3/envs/clone-test/lib/python36.zip', '~/miniconda3/envs/clone-test/lib/python3.6', '~/miniconda3/envs/clone-test/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '~/miniconda3/envs/clone-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages']` no mention of the original environment at all. So I definitely can't reproduce this on my mac. Are you sure the global environment is being preferred over the cloned environment?

Comment: As for copying the entire environment, yes, this is the expected behavior. However, I'm pretty sure conda uses hardlinks so the disk usage is minimized

Comment: That's so strange. After `source activate` I see `>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/conda/miniconda3/4.4.10-login/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '~/git/python_tools', '~/anconda_envs/test/lib/python36.zip', '~/anconda_envs/test/lib/python3.6', '~/anconda_envs/test/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '~/anconda_envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

Comment: What version of conda do you have? What if you do `conda activate <env-path>` instead of `source activate <env-path>`?

Comment: Thanks for the continuing suggestions, but `conda activate` still places the new environment's site-packages folder at the end of the `sys.path`. Strangely, the folder in which I call `conda activate /path/to/new/env` is the first entry in this list.